# Is this the right way of building an Erlang network server for multi-client apps?

Tags: erlang, multiplayer, mnesia

I'm building a small network server for a multi-player board game using Erlang.
This network server uses a local instance of Mnesia DB to store a session for each connected client app. Inside each client's record (session) stored in this local Mnesia, I store the client's PID and NODE (the node where a client is logged in).

I plan to deploy this network server on at least 2 connected servers (Node A & B).
So in order to allow a Client A who is logged in on Node A to search (query to Mnesia) for a Client B who is logged in on Node B, I replicate the Mnesia session table from Node A to Node B or vise-versa.

After Client A queries the PID and NODE of the Client B, then Client A and B can communicate with each other directly.

**Is this the right way of establishing connection between two client apps that are logged-in on two different Erlang nodes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a system where two or more nodes are perfectly in sync is by definition impossible. In practice however, you might get close enough that it works for your particular problem.

You don't say the exact reason behind running on two nodes, so I'm going to assume it is for scalability. With many nodes, your system will also be more available and fault-tolerant if you get it right. However, the problem could be simplified if you know you only ever will run in a single node, and need the other node as a hot-slave to take over if the master is unavailable.

To establish a connection between two processes on two different nodes, you need some global addressing(user id 123 is pid<123,456,0>). If you also care about only one process running for User A running at a time, you also need a lock or allow only unique registrations of the addressing. If you also want to grow, you need a way to add more nodes, either while your system is running or when it is stopped.

Now, there are already some solutions out there that helps solving your problem, with different trade-offs:

- gproc in global mode, allows registering a process under a given key(which gives you addressing and locking). This is distributed to the entire cluster, with no single point of failure, however the leader election (at least when I last looked at it) works only for nodes that was available when the system started. Adding new nodes requires an experimental version of gen_leader or stopping the system. Within your own code, if you know two players are only going to ever talk to each other, you could start them on the same node.
- riak_core, allows you to build on top of the well-tested and proved architecture used in riak KV and riak search. It maps the keys into buckets in a fashion that allows you to add new nodes and have the keys redistributed. You can plug into this mechanism and move your processes. This approach does not let you decide where to start your processes, so if you have much communication between them, this will go across the network.
- Using mnesia with distributed transactions, allows you to guarantee that every node has the data before the transaction is commited, this would give you distribution of the addressing and locking, but you would have to do everything else on top of this(like releasing the lock). Note: I have never used distributed transactions in production, so I cannot tell you how reliable they are. Also, due to being distributed, expect latency. Note2: You should check exactly how you would add more nodes and have the tables replicated, for example if it is possible without stopping mnesia.
- Zookeper/doozer/roll your own, provides a centralized highly-available database which you may use to store the addressing. In this case you would need to handle unregistering yourself. Adding nodes while the system is running is easy from the addressing point of view, but you need some way to have your application learn about the new nodes and start spawning processes there.

Also, it is not necessary to store the node, as the pid contains enough information to send the messages directly to the correct node.

As a cool trick which you may already be aware of, pids may be serialized (as may *all* data within the VM) to a binary. Use `term_to_binary/1` and `binary_to_term/1` to convert between the actual pid inside the VM and a binary which you may store in whatever accepts binary data without mangling it in some stupid way.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Knutin :) ... as you may guess that I'm very new to Erlang (6 months).

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, you should mark it as "accepted". I noticed that you have asked other questions which also has been answered without you marking the best answer as accepted. Please do mark them as such, as that's the way StackOverflow is meant to work.

Comment: I'm sorry ... but where is "accepted" button? sorry I really just knew from you ... thanks